# How to create animations for images?

Tags: android, animation

> I want such animation on images that when images screen is loaded images come from sides like two images come from top and other two from right and left side. can anyone please help me to implement such animations?

Comment: Have you checked android website? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html or even http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm

Comment: what you have tried  ?

Comment: i have tried animation like sequential animations but got no help